# d3.js Force Chart with zoomable/pan

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating a force chart that has expandable/collapsible parts. I am trying to integrate a zooming/panning feature into the chart, but its only working when you interact (pan/mousewheel) on an actual node - not essentially the chart itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/837/

```
var svg = d3.select("#chartHolder")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.attr("pointer-events", "all")
.append('svg:g')
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
.append('svg:g');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/QMKm3/
^ this example is what I am trying to mimic - and it works accordingly to interacting with empty spaces in the chart.

Comment: How could the code "http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/837/" be modified to allow pan/zoom on non-node areas.

Answer (score 1):

all you gotta do is remove the first append "g";

```
var svg = d3.select("#chartHolder")
  .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("pointer-events", "all")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
  .append('svg:g');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/frankcastro/qv42nt7o/1/

Comment: Hello Frank, that is great - it enables the zoom/pan - but it stops the click actions for expanding/collapsing the nodes. Also when you try and drag the children - it pans instead